# How to install CD burning on 24.04

Tags: cd, burning, 24.04

Ubuntu 24.04 does not have any software that will burn a audio CD.
There is no software centre to install from.
Many of the apps that come with Ububtu 24.04 have lost the three button top left, close, min, full screen. The only way to close some apps is right click the taskbar icon and click QUIT

Comment: sudo apt install wodim

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *mantic* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Answer (score 3):

While your question is off-topic on this site because 24.04 is not released yet, you can install Brasero to burn CD/DVD in any version of Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt install brasero
```

For the missing icons, you can create a bug report in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). See [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/124466)